# How do sites like SO find highly relevant, related Q&A?

Tags: discussion

Even without entering tags, SO and other Q&A sites s.a. Quora manage to find (often) highly relevant existing Q&A, to the new question that I am entering. How does this work ? Had it been based on bayesian classification based on tags used, I could understand, but from freeform text, this kind of identification of other relevant content, seems almost magical. What kind of algorithms are used ?

Comment: Are you refering to the question list that opens when you ask a new question?

Comment: It probably filters out common short words (_"the, it, and, that, I, etc..."_), possibly identifies keywords in the text you've entered so far, and returns a result based on that.

Comment: I believe SO make use of [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org)

Comment: @juergend, indeed, the list of questions that opens when asking new question.

Comment: Thanks all. Hadn't known about elasticsearch.org ! I'd then perhaps go back to SO and try to ask about the type of algorithms that elasticsearch is using, unless I find some paper about it. Would that be an acceptable thing to do ? Given that this question was migrated to SO-meta (which I understand why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listened to a case study a while ago which SO mentioned they use [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org).

Elastic search has a great feature called [More Like This](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) So I imagine they use this feature to determine relevant questions, along with removing stop words (and,i,the,etc) as @Cerbrus mentioned.

It also has the ability to use [stemming](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stemming.html) to merge different words/variations which have the same meaning. So this might be a big part of finding relevant questions.

Comment: A simple experiment: using [A Random Query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+do+active+answerers+find+questions+to+answer%3F), you can see the found terms are **bold**, also when the stem is the same ("answering"), and the stop word "to" is ignored. ("Active" appears to be a stop word as well. Perhaps SO amended the list?)

Comment: That's interesting that "active" appears to be a stopword.. seems like an odd one to exclude from searches but perhaps the history of queries would shed light on the decision (if there was a decision to do that)